# Go build single or separate cache directory

Tags: go, build

I have multiple Go projects that are caching their build in the default `GOCACHE` directory. According to Golang's official [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_and_test_caching):

> The go command periodically deletes cached data that has not been used recently. Running 'go clean -cache' deletes all cached data.

So if I understand it correctly, it seems likely that `go build` will overwrite these cache as the number of project builds increase. Therefore, is it beneficial to keep each project's build cache in a separate location?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. Keep a single cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each package has it's own cache.  There is no advantage in having separate locations.